# Why am I getting 'Error: Error serializing ___ returned from getStaticProps'?

Tags: json, next.js, apollo

I am receiving the following error when I call inside `getStaticProps` and I cannot figure out why:

```
Error: Error serializing `.lingo` returned from `getStaticProps` in "/".
Reason: `undefined` cannot be serialized as JSON.
```

I've placed the full app code on [CodeSandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/loving-gould-zs5gw). It won't be able to access the API but it does show where things are defined.

When I run the following query on GraphQL playground I get the expected response:

```
query {
   allTerms {
      id
      term
      slug
      lead
   }
}
```

You can see that this query is contained in `lingo.service.js` in the `modules/lingo/services` directory on the sandbox but the homepage has the `Error serializing` error. Is my function `export async function getAll()` not correct or am I calling it wrong in `getStaticProps`?

Comment: Any time you see `cannot ____ undefined` or something similar in an error message it is because one of your variables is equal to undefined when it shouldn't be.

Answer (score 0):

`await getAll()` is most likely returning `undefined` which is not serializable JSON.  Defaulting to `null` would be one way to solve the issue.

```js
export async function getStaticProps(context) {
  return {
    props: { lingo: (await getAll()) ?? null },
  };
}
```

Comment: Thanks. Would `null` not return anything though? There are items to respond and they do get responded when queried in GraphQL Playground. The other issue is that `lingo.length` now returns `null` and causes a `TypeError: Cannot read property 'length' of null` error.

Comment: You'll need to adjust your code around it potentially being `null`. Adding extra checks before accessing `lingo.length`, for example. Or not even rendering certain components at all when it's null.

Answer (score 0):

Right, this is supposed to be more of a comment but apparently I don't have enough reputation points to comment. So, I'll answer it like this.

> Just check if your props (under `getStaticProps()`) are named correctly i.e. how they're named in the .json file you're trying to read. I ran into this issue because of a typo I had and just fixed it.